# What is term for the most general form of writing or text

Tags: word-requests

Typing **The article/text/writing was innovative** in any translation software gives numerous results. After looking up the words *article*, *text*, and *writing* in the dictionary, I found too many options and so, decided to choose the most basic word that would get the meaning of *a visible piece of text* through.

I need a word that in general can encompass things such as writings in a cave, an article in the newspaper, a notice on the notice board, an essay written by a student, etc.

Or there are too many to sift through and I should memorize them separately. BTW, I found *きじ* and. *てくすと* but am not sure if they can collectively handle broad meanings.

Is there a general term for **texts** in japanese like fluid is for everything that flows?

Comment: What aspects "writings in a cave, an article in the newspaper, a notice on the notice board, an essay written by a student" have in common, if you don't mind?

Answer (score 2):

We may not have a perfect counterpart.  The best I could think of would be 「文章{ぶんしょう}」.

If, however, the writing consisted of only a few letters/characters, we might call it 「文字{もじ}」.

Answer (score 0):

文字{もじ} would be a right word in this case.