# How to say "essay" in Japanese

Tags: words

How to say "a student essay"?

A simple text written of around 50 to 150 words for a foreign language class.

I found 論文 but I am afraid it means something longer, for more specialized fields like history, economics etc.
And there is the translation 文章*, but it also means "sentence" (?).

*[What is term for the most general form of writing or text](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/44374/what-is-term-for-the-most-general-form-of-writing-or-text)

Comment: How about 作文?  https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BD%9C%E6%96%87

Answer (score 1):

小論文or随筆or評論or感想文

と訳せるとは思いますが、いずれも微妙に意味が違うので、essayは「エッセイ」と記すことが多いです。

日本においては

essay＝｛エッセイ｝⊃｛小論文、随筆、評論、感想文｝

というようにessayにあたる訳語が多数あり、一対一になっていないので、文章の内容によって訳し分ける必要があるのです。